# Event Handler behavioral difference .net 1.1 vs 2.0 with null delegate

Tags: .net-2.0, delegates, events, .net-1.1, nullreferenceexception

Not sure what exactly is going on here, but seems like in .NET 1.1 an uninitialized event delegate can run without issues, but in .NET 2.0+ it causes a NullReferenceException.  Any ideas why.  The code below will run fine without issues in 1.1, in 2.0 it gives a NullReferenceException.  I'm curious why does it behave differently?  What changed?

Thanks

eg

```
class Class1
    {
    public delegate void ChartJoinedRowAddedHandler(object sender);



    public static event ChartJoinedRowAddedHandler ChartJoinedRowAdded;
    public static DataTable dt;

    public static void Main()
    {           
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableEventHandler);

        object [] obj = new object[]{1,2};
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Last");
        dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(obj);
    }

    private static void TableEventHandler(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ChartJoinedRowAdded(new object());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated] AFAIK, there was no change here to the fundamental delegate handling; the difference is in how DataTable behaves.

However! Be very careful using static events, especially if you are subscribing from instances (rather than static methods). This is a good way to keep huge swathes of objects alive and not be garbage collected.

Running the code via csc from 1.1 shows that the general delegate side is the same - I think the difference is that the DataTable code that raises RowChanged was swallowing the exception. For example, make the code like below:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    ChartJoinedRowAdded(new object());
    Console.WriteLine("After");
```

You'll see "Before", but no "After"; an exception was thrown and swallowed by the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

The eventhandler system is basically just a list of functions to call when a given event is raised.

It initializes to the "null" list, and not the empty list, so you need to do

```
if (ChartJoinedRowAdded != null)
      ChartJoinedRowAdded(new object())
```

Answer (score 0):

The way events work hasn't really changed from 1.1 to 2

Although the syntax looks like normal aggregation it really isn't:

```
dt.RowChanged += TableEventHandler;
dt.RowChanged += null;
dt.RowChanged += delegate (object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
    //anon
};
```

Will fire `TableEventHandler` and then the delegate - the null is just skipped.

You can use null to clear events, but only inside the event firing class:

```
this.MyEvent = null;
```

If nothing subscribes your event will be null - see soraz's answer. The `DataTable` class will contain a similar check and won't fire the event if there are no subscribers.

The standard pattern is:

```
//events should just about always use this pattern: object, args
public static event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ChartJoinedRowAdded;


//inheriting classes can override this event behaviour
protected virtual OnChartJoinedRowAdded() {
    if( ChartJoinedRowAdded != null )
        ChartJoinedRowAdded( this, new MyEventArgs(...) );
}
```